# Chrome Version 44.0.2403.157 m Won't Apply Class After 300 or More Entries in Picklist

Tags: css, google-chrome, picklist

I found an issue with Chrome Version 44.0.2403.157 m. The issue has to do with HTML pick lists. I have a pick list that has a total of 738 entries. Of those 738 entries there are 620 of them that do not have a class assigned to them, they are my active entries in the pick list, and there are 118 that have a class assigned to them that changes the background and foreground colors. I do this so the users can see all the items in the pick list, but visually identify the ones that are not active. The problem I have is that as soon as I pass 300 entries in the pick list, for example 301 or greater no matter if its an option with the class or not, the class is no longer applied to the pick list. I have example code, here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/oxoa4ceo.

```
.css_inactive-format {
 /* color: #0000FF; */
 color: #ffffff;
 background: #d9d7d7; 
}

<select name="trade_company">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1831255ON">1831255ON (1831255ON) 16 PETER ANDREW </option>
<option class="css_inactive-format" value="AIG">AIG TRADING CORP.</option>
```

This link shows how it looks with 300 entries and you can see the class being applied correctly (scroll to the bottom). If you move the comment blocks around, so that there are more than 300 items in the pick list, you can see that the class no longer works. If you drop it down to 300 or less, the class will be correctly applied again. I know this is a long message to explain the issue, but once you run the JSFiddle code it will be simple to see what is happening.

Comment: for me everything fine - first 310 items works with standard styles, and another ones with your `.css_inactive-format`

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using. I have multiple users at work, all on Chrome 44, and they all exhibit the same behavior. I know it worked on a prior version of Chrome, but not working in Chrome Version 44.0.2403.157 m.

Comment: ohh, sorry I missed one number in my version. I need to update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Option tag classes are not being applied in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189180/option-tag-classes-not-being-applied-in-chrome).