# Option tag classes are not being applied in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I believe there is a bug in Chrome, specifically version 44.0.2403.157 m.

I have an "inactive" CSS class I apply to `<option>` tags of a `<select>` element. My list has 300+ entries in it. The class applies and appears correctly when I have **300 or less** `<option>` tags. However, as soon as I add the 301st `<option>` tag, the class is no longer applied to any of the elements. This never used to be the case, I just started noticing it with Chrome version 44.

Here's an example. By default, I have exactly 300 `<option>` tags listed and as you can see if you scroll down the list, the class applies correctly. Please uncomment the final tag at the bottom and you will see that with the 301st element, the styling disappears.

```css
.css_inactive-format {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #d9d7d7; 
}
```

```html
<select name="trade_company">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1831255ON">1831255ON (1831255ON) 16 PETER ANDREW THORNHILL</option>
    <option value="200 SOUTH">200 SOUTH ENERGY (200 SOUTH) 4580 ADAMS AVE MIAMI BEACH</option>
    <option value="4ACRIB">4ACRIB (4ACRIB)</option>
    <option class="css_inactive-format" value="AMOCOOIL">AMOCO OIL COMPANY (AMOCOOIL) 28100 TORCH PARKWAY WARRENVILLE</option>
    <option class="css_inactive-format" value="AMOCOOILCO">AMOCO OIL COMPANY (AMOCOOILCO) P.O. BOX 3092 HOUSTON</option>
    <option class="css_inactive-format" value="AMOCOPETPR">AMOCO PETROLEUM PRODUCTS (AMOCOPETPR) P.O. BOX 3092 HOUSTON</option>
    <option class="css_inactive-format" value="AMOCOPETPR">AMOCO PETROLEUM PRODUCTS (AMOCOPETPR) P.O. BOX 3092 HOUSTON</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oxoa4ceo/3/

Any ideas?

Comment: I can confirm I experienced the same behaviour in latest Opera, while Firefox does it fine. Could be webkit related.

Comment: And here is the bug report https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in Chrome 44, that has been fixed in Chrome 46, per easwee's comment:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513339#c14

Specifically:

> The latest canary, 46.0.2468.0, fixed this issue.
>   https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html
>
> Everyone, would you check if the canary fixes your problems please?

And

> Approved for M45 (branch: 2454)
>
> Labels: -Merge-Request-45 Merge-Approved-45 Hotlist-Merge-Approved